# xargs and vi - "Input is not from a terminal"

Tags: command-line, terminal, vi, xargs

I have about 10 `php.ini` files on my system, located all over the place, and I wanted to quickly browse through them. I tried this command:

```
locate php.ini | xargs vi
```

But `vi` warns me `Input is not from a terminal` and then the console starts getting really weird - after which I need to press `:q!` to quit `vi` and then disconnect from the ssh session and reconnect to have the console behave normally again.

I think that I sort of understand what's happening here - basically the command hasn't finished when `vi` started so the command maybe hasn't finished and `vi` doesn't think that the terminal is in normal mode.

I have no idea how to fix it. I have searched Google and also unix.stackexchange.com with poor luck.

Comment: [Same question on SU](http://superuser.com/q/336016/92173).

Comment: As a side note, you can run `reset` to reset your terminal when it gets screwed up (you don't have to disconnect from ssh session).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
vi $(locate php.ini)
```

Note: this will have issues if your file paths have space, tabs, newline (which are in the default value of `$IFS`) or glob characters, but it is functionally similar to your command (`xargs` does treat quote and backslash characters specially, which this doesn't do though).
This next version will properly handle space, tab and glob characters but is a bit more complicated *(newlines in file names will still break it though)*

```
(IFS=$'\n'; set -o noglob; vi $(locate php.ini))
```

#### Explanation:

What's happening is that programs inherit their file descriptors from the process that spawned them. `xargs` has its STDIN connected to the STDOUT of `locate`, so `vi` has no clue what the original STDIN really in.

Comment: xargs is wonderful, one of my favourite tools - it's just not suited for use with programs that use stdin for anything other than a data feed. i like your answer and your explanation other than that, so +1 anyway :)

Comment: @CraigSanders I don't like it because it's too easy to abuse (use improperly) and end up breaking. I've never run into anything that I've absolutely had to use `xargs` for that couldn't be done directly with the shell (or `find`). However I can think of cases where it would be the best solution. So, so long as you understand what `xargs` is doing, how it splits up the arguments, how it runs the program, etc, and are using it properly, I'd say go for it :-P

Comment: it can't be beat for things like `... | awk '{print $3}' | xargs | sed -e 's/ /+/g' | bc` (to add up all the values of field 3).  or with `sed -e 's/ /|/g'` to construct a regexp.  and yes, like any tool, you do need to know how to use it and what its limitations and caveats are.

Comment: The `vi $(...)` approach also has a problem with wildcards in shells other than `zsh`.

Comment: Also note that with the `xargs` approach beside the whitespace issue, file names with single quotes, double quotes and backslashes are also a problem.

Comment: Note that depending on the `xargs` implementation, in `xargs cmd`, `cmd` inherits the file descriptor or `xargs` makes `cmd`'s stdin `/dev/null` opened in read-only mode which is generally a better idea as it avoids `cmd` interfering with `xargs`'s input (that's the latter with GNU `xargs`).

Answer (score 23):

This question has previously been asked on the [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/336016/invoking-vi-through-find-xargs-breaks-my-terminal-why) forum.

Quoting from @grawity's answer on that question:

> When you invoke a program via xargs, the program's stdin (standard
> input) points to /dev/null. (Since xargs doesn't know the original
> stdin, it does the next best thing.)
>
> Vim expects its stdin to be the same as its controlling terminal, and
> performs various terminal-related ioctl's on stdin directly. When done
> on /dev/null (or any non-tty file descriptor), those ioctls are
> meaningless and return ENOTTY, which gets silently ignored.

Both the OS X/macOS/BSD and recent versions of GNU findutils' `xargs` (beginning with [v4.6.0](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?51151)) have a `-o` option to address this exact scenario:

From the macOS/BSD man page:

> -o      Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process
> before executing the command.  This is useful
> if you want xargs to run an interactive application.

Hence, on macOS, you could use the following command:

```
find . -name "php.ini" | xargs -o vim
```

If you are stuck with an older version of GNU `xargs`, the following command will work. (Make sure to include the `dummy` string, otherwise it will drop the first file.)

```
find . -name "php.ini" | xargs bash -c '</dev/tty vim "$@"' dummy
```

The above solutions are courtesy [Jaime McGuigan on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/427881). Adding them here for any future visitors searching the site for this error.

Comment: +1  thanks for the -o tip.  i've been using xargs for years and never noticed that....just checked the man page on my system, that's because it's not a GNU xargs feature.  The man page does provide `xargs sh -c 'emacs "$@" < /dev/tty' emacs` as what they claim is a more flexible and portable alternative (although it's kind of funny for GNU to be prefer portability to features :).

Comment: Without dummy string: `'<dev/tty "$0" "$@"' vim`

Comment: The `-o` (also `--open-tty`) has been ported to xargs (GNU findutils) 4.8.0.

Comment: @BigMcLargeHuge as of [4.6.0](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/commit/xargs/xargs.c?id=40cd25147b4461979c0d992299f2c101f9034f7a), which was back in 2017, so any recent installation of GNU findutils should have this option now.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `findutils`, and a shell with support for process substitution (ksh, zsh, bash), you can do:

```
xargs -r0a <(locate -0 php.ini) vi
```

The idea being to pass the file list via a `-a filename` rather than stdin. Using `-0` makes sure it works regardless of what characters or non-characters the file names may contain.

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
vi ${(0)"$(locate -0 php.ini)"}
```

(where `0` is the parameter expansion flag to split on NULs).

However note that contrary to `xargs -r` that still runs `vi` without argument if no file is found.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens when vim is invoked and it's connected to the previous pipeline's output, instead of the terminal and it's receiving different unexpected input (like NULs).
The same happens when you run: `vim < /dev/null`, so `reset` command in this case helps. This is explained well by [grawity at superuser](https://superuser.com/a/336020/87805).

On BSD/OSX or with GNU xargs since version 4.7.0, you can use `xargs` with `-o` parameter, like:

```
locate php.ini | xargs -o vim
```

> <sup>`-o` Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before executing the command.  This is useful if you want xargs to run an interactive application.</sup>

With `xargs` implementations that don't support `-o`, try the following workaround:

```
locate php.ini | xargs sh -c 'exec vim < /dev/tty "$@"' sh
```

Alternatively use GNU `parallel` instead of `xargs` to force tty allocation, in example:

```
locate php.ini | parallel -X --tty vi
```

<sup>Note: `parallel`on Unix/OSX won't work as it has different parameters and it doesn't support tty.</sup>

<sup>Many other popular commands provides pseudo-tty allocation as well (like `-t` in `ssh`), so check for help.</sup>

Alternatively use `find` to pass file names to edit, so don't need `xargs`, just use `-exec`, in example:

```
find /etc -name php.ini -exec vim {} +
```

Comment: `xargs -J` is not available on GNU Linux. Can you give the output of `bash -c 'echo $OSTYPE'` (or `zsh -c 'echo $OSTYPE'`) (or `uname -o` if available) on the system where you're able to use `xargs -J` ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit multiple php.ini within the same editor ?

Try:  `vim -o $(locate php.ini)`

Answer (score 0):

@Patrick's `IFS` hack is only necessary for dumb shells like `bash` and `zsh`. `fish`  splits the string on newlines by default.

```
$ vim (locate php.ini)
```

And God help us all if a single one of us actually has a file with a newline in its name. After 17 years using Linux, I haven't seen it even once. I'd only bother supporting filenames with newlines in them for scripts that have to work no matter what, but scripts like that probably aren't running vim interactively.

Comment: `zsh` splits on SPC, TAB, NL and NUL by default. The thing it doesn't do compared to `bash` is perform globbing on the result so wildcard characters in file names are not a problem. In `zsh`, you'd do `IFS=$'\0'; vi $(locate -0 php.ini)` or as I shown in my answer `vi ${(0)"$(locate -0 php.ini)"}` for an explicit splitting operator. Also note tcsh's `vi "\`locate php.ini\`"`

Comment: aw, crap. OK this works: `$ f='not there'<ret>$ ls $f<ret>` but this doesn't: ls `echo not there`. OK looks like I need to update this a bit.

Comment: Yeah, zsh doesn't do the right thing when you do `ls "$(echo test; echo other test)"`. Only fish does the right thing.

Comment: Assuming you meant the same without the quotes, that's not "right", that's splitting on lines, it's just a different choice. zsh splits on words by default (like all other shells) and can be told to split on lines or on NULs, either via `$IFS` or via explicit operators (`f` and `0` parameter expansion flags). For arbitrary file names, splitting by word or splitting by line is equally *wrong*, you need to split on NUL or parse some encoding, which `fish` can't do. In `zsh`, that's `IFS=$'\0'; ls -ld -- $(printf '%s\0' "$file1" "$file2")` or `ls -ld -- ${(0)"$(printf '%s\0' "$file1" "$file2")"}`

Comment: Meh. Splitting on newlines is good enough. Like the answer says, newlines in filenames are extremely rare. I have literally never seen it happen in 17 years. And newlines are way more convenient separators than nuls.

Comment: `mkdir -p $'/tmp/\n/etc/shadow\n/file~'`. There, you've seen it now ;-), the excuse no longer stands and your `rm -f (find /tmp -name '*~')` will remove `/etc/shadow`. It's not about how common it is or not, it's about whether it's possible or not. File paths are sequences of bytes other than 0. To handle them reliably, you have to treat them as binary blobs.

Answer (score 0):

**The "`vi`" way** (vs the "`ex` way") is historically more like:

```
vi /tmp/$$.out
~
~
:r!locate php.ini
```

Instead of trying to pipe to `vi` from stdin or stdout (which is not normally supported outside of `vim`-alikes), you open `vi` and use `ex` Command mode to execute your "shell stuff".  Then you can munge the results in-place.

This method should work in any proper `ex` implementation.  `vi` is traditionally just a **V**isual **I**nterface to `ex`.
Or putting it another way, `ex -v` is more commonly known / executed as "**`vi`**" for short.

You could even perform these kinds of operations with a macro (`@`) in Input mode and/or use `u`ndo to make changes and/or corrections.

**The `ex` way**

If you want to do it in a script then it could be with `ex` commands from a here-doc or something:

```
tmp=/tmp/$$.out
ex -s ${tmp} <<'EOS'
r!locate php.ini
wq
EOS
vi ${tmp}
```

You can use almost any combination of valid scripting / `sh` or `ex` commands with this method, such as the `find` suggestion from others.

This could also be done with `ed` but I was never one of the cool kids.

Again, `ex` is POSIX, so it should work in GNU/Linux, *BSD, HP-UX, AIX, etc.

**Variation**

Presuming there are no security concerns, you might redirect to a file first then munge it separately, depending on your use case:

```
tmp=/tmp/$$.out
locate php.ini > ${tmp}
vi ${tmp}
```

**However...**

If just browsing is truly your goal then you may only need something like:

```
locate php.ini | more
```

I am throwing that out there because we can all over-complicate simple things at times.