# How to `locate` multiple files and open them in vim?

Tags: command-line, terminal, vim, io-redirection, locate

Suppose that I have a file named `filename123.txt` and it is the single file that is named so, and I can `locate` it with the command `locate filename123`. And it returns only this file.

Now I want to open it with `vi`/`vim`. But I don't want to go to that location and type the `vi` command followed by filename. Here I want the result of `locate filename123` to be appended to the vi command. How can I do so? I already tried:

```
locate filename123 | vi
```

But this does not works. And this error comes in terminal:

```
santosh@santosh:~$ locate filename123 | vi
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: Finished.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [xargs and vi - "Input is not from a terminal"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44426/xargs-and-vi-input-is-not-from-a-terminal)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `xargs`:

```
locate filename123 | xargs vi
```

By default `xargs` will execute as few instances of the specified command as possible, passing as many parameters as possible according to the system's [ARG_MAX](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/). To limit the number of parameters passed to an instance of `vi`, use `xargs`' `-n` option.

To handle file names containing spaces use `xargs`' `-d` option:

```
locate filename123 | xargs -d '\n' vi
```

To handle file names containing newlines use `xargs`' `-0` option together with `locate`'s `-0` option:

```
locate -0 filename123 | xargs -0 vi
```

(If `-0` is not available on any of them, check for `--null` too, or another way to specify character `\000` as delimiter.)

Comment: Can you tell me what is what was preventing me before to open this file?

Comment: @Santosh You were passing the output of the `locate` command as *input* to vi. Vi, like any other program, expects the name of the file(s) to work on as arguments.

Comment: @manatwork The problem is I can't locate and open filename with spaces in it. E.g. this command will open multiple files in vim: locate I\ have\ to\ download | xargs vi

Answer (score 3):

You could use command expansion:

```
vi "$(locate filename123 | head -n1)"
```

To make `vim` read its stdin you can do `vim -`, but that will just give you the output of `locate` which are filename paths. This might work though, using `vim` `gf` normal command will then open the path that the cursor is on.

#### Edit

In the case of filenames with spaces in them you're better of using the `xargs` option mentioned or the `vim` solution described above. Note to make `gf` work you need to add space to `isfname`:

```
set isfname+=32
```

This tip and alternatives are described [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor).

#### Edit 2

Added quotes and `head` as suggested by PeterO in the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45782/trying-to-locate-and-then-open-a-file#comment63391_45787).

Comment: For file with whitespaces in them, when I insert \ in file name, like vi $(locate another\ file). The vim opens it as two separate files, `another` and `file` :(.

Comment: Your answer only works when I have no spaces in the file which I am locating.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: @Thor: For a single file, as mentioned in the question, you just need to wrap quotes around the process-substitution: `vi "$(locate filename123)"` ... To ensure that it has *only one* file name to deal with: `vi "$(locate filename123 |head -n1)"`

Comment: PeterO: You're right, I only tested with multiple hits. I've added your comments to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to pass `locate` as [shell substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution), like:

```
vim $(locate filename123)
```

You can also consider to use `find` instead of `locate` to pass file names to edit, in example:

```
find . -name 'filename123' -exec vim {} +
```

On Unix/OSX you can use `xargs` with `-o` parameter, like:

```
locate filename123 | xargs -o vim
```

> <sup>`-o` Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before executing the command.  This is useful if you want xargs to run an interactive application.</sup>

Or on Linux try the following workaround using:

```
locate filename123 | xargs -J% sh -c 'vim < /dev/tty $@'
```

If you're using different commands, use [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) to achieve that, like:

```
vim $(locate filename123)
vim `locate filename123`
```

Alternatively use GNU `parallel` instead of `xargs` to force tty allocation, in example:

```
locate filename123 | parallel -X --tty vi
```

<sup>Note: `parallel`on Unix/OSX won't work as it has different parameters and it doesn't support tty.</sup>

<sup>Many other popular commands provides pseudo-tty allocation as well (like `-t` in `ssh`), so check for help.</sup>

Other suggestion would be to use [`vipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/vipe) (a Vim command pipe) or use the following simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# usage: locate filename123 | vip
exec vim < /dev/tty "$@"
```

Related:

- [Terminal borked after invoking Vim with xargs](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/410/467) at Vim SE