# How can I display the contents of a text file on the command line?

Tags: command-line, files, cat

I would like to display the contents of a text file on the command line. The file only contains 5-6 characters. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Just a reminder, the question is for Linux, for Windows you use `type filename` command

Answer (score 387, accepted):

#### Using `cat`

Since your file is short, you can use
[`cat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29).

```
cat filename
```

#### Using `less`

If you have to view the contents of a longer file, you can use a pager such as
[`less`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29).

```
less filename
```

You can make `less` behave like `cat` when invoked on small files and behave
normally otherwise by passing it the `-F` and `-X` flags.

```
less -FX filename
```

I have an alias for `less -FX`. You can make one yourself like so:

```
alias aliasname='less -FX'
```

If you add the alias to your [shell
configuration](http://hacktux.com/bash/bashrc/bash_profile), you can use it
forever.

#### Using `od`

If your file contains strange or unprintable characters, you can use
[`od`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/od) to examine the characters. For example,

```
$ cat file
(ÐZ4 ?o=÷jï
$ od -c test
0000000 202 233   ( 320   K   j 357 024   J 017   h   Z   4 240   ?   o
0000020   = 367  \n
0000023
```

Comment: +1, also `sed -n l file` could be useful.

Comment: Does `less` have any clear advantages over other pager programs like [`pg`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pg_%28Unix%29), or does it just boil down to personal preference?

Comment: @SamWeinberg: `less` has more features than `pg`. Take a look at the [`less(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less) and [`pg(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/pg.1.html) manpages. There are other pagers as well. Take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81129/what-are-the-differences-between-most-more-and-less/81131#81131. `less` is probably the most widely-used pager but which one you use comes down to personal preference.

Comment: don't forget `more` and `most`!

Comment: You can also use the `tail` command to see the last lines of text.

Comment: `cat` may be simple and easy, but using it like this will not pass Shellcheck.

Comment: `tail` is particularly useful for looking at large log files, since the most recent logs are usually at the bottom

Answer (score 62):

Even though everybody uses `cat filename` to print a files text to the standard output first purpose is con**cat**enating.
From cat's man page:

> cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output

Now cat is fine for printing files but there are alternatives:

```
  echo "$(<filename)"
or
  printf "%s" "$(<filename)"
```

The `( )` return the value of an expression, in this case the content of *filename* which then is expanded by `$` for `echo` or `printf`.

Update:

```
< filename
```

This does exactly what you want and is easy to remember.

Here is an example that lets you select a file in a menu and then prints it.

```
#!/bin/bash

select fname in *;
do
# Don't forget the "" around the second part, else newlines won't be printed
  printf "%s" "$(<$fname)"
  break
done
```

For further reading:
[BashPitfalls - cat file | sed s/foo/bar/ > file](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file)
[Bash Reference - Redirecting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections)

Comment: Your update: "`< filename` is exactly what you want, ..." is misleading. Overall, although this is an interesting discussion on alternatives, I think `cat` is simpler.

Comment: Bare `< filename` does not display contents of the file, but `cat filename` does.

Comment: You could use `tee < filename`, too.

Comment: +1 for the `echo "$(<filename)"` bashism. Not enough of that here.

Comment: That's great idea for using Linux Internal Command with echo `"$(<filename)"`. Thanks ...

Comment: @jarno Why bare `< filename` does not display contents of the file?

Comment: I've tested, `< filename` only works on zsh and not on GNU bash version 5.1.16(1)-release.

Comment: Fun fact: use echo without double quote `echo $(<filename)` print files without new lines.
write file contents in one line on standard output.

Comment: `cat`'s primarily use is to concatenate, but among all the commands that can dump the contents of a file, it's one of the rare ones that doesn't modify it in the process. Your `$(...)` removes trailing newline characters, in bash removes the NULs, `echo` does further modifications if there are backslashes or it starts with `-`. In bash, that still forks a process and the contents has to be fed through a pipe and stored whole several times in memory. Really not an improvement over `cat file`.

Comment: @jarno, `< filename` works in zsh where it does `$READNULLCMD < filename`, `$READNULLCMD` being a pager by default.

Comment: Be very careful with **<filename**. A simple mistake of writing **>filename** instead can destroy your file!

Answer (score 21):

Tools for handling text files on unix are basic, everyday-commands:

In unix and linux to print out whole content in file

```
cat filename.txt
```

or

```
more filename.txt
```

or

```
less filename.txt
```

For last few lines

```
tail filename.txt
```

For first few lines

```
head filename.txt
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use following command to display content of a text file.

```
cat filename
```

Comment: For more information about `cat`, run `man cat`.

Answer (score 7):

One option is to use `more`

e.g. `more file.txt`

However it does not have all the feature added by `less`.
One simple example is that you can't scroll back up in the output.  Generally it has been superceeded by less - which was named in jest because

> less is more

Comment: Nice explanation on why less was the name

Answer (score 4):

I always use `$ less "your file here"` , as it is very simple, provides a built in interactive `grep` command, and gives you an easy to use interface that you can scroll with the arrow keys.

(It is also included on nearly every *nix system)

Comment: `less` is the overkill-version of `more` (compare `man less` with `man more`), and for me it has two annoying features: 1) it switches to the alternate screen buffer, when less terminates, the file you were just viewing vanishes 2) at EOF you have to explicitly type `q` (I know, there's an option for this). So one of my first actions in a new environment is setting `export PAGER=/bin/more` in my profile and use `more` all the time.

Comment: @ott--: 1) Try out the `-X` flag. 2) Try out the `-E` flag. `less` has a `more` emulation mode. You can enable it by setting the `LESS_IS_MORE` environmental variable. You can scroll upwards in the `more` emulation mode.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81129/what-are-the-differences-between-most-more-and-less/81131#81131

Comment: Though, in general, I do agree that `less` is overly-complicated. Its ability to run external commands is a perfect example of its over-complexity.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman I've always found the grep functionality extremely useful myself, @ott-- I find that because of it's emulation of `more`, and it's many additional features, it does the job very well.

Comment: @ott-- I've never had problems with `less`'s alternate screen buffer, as it only does this when the file to show will not fit on the screen in its entirety.

Answer (score 3):

If its a large file, and you want to search some specific part, you can use

```
 cat filename | grep text_to_search -ni
```

Also you can use more interactive Vim editor (or vi editor if you do not have Vim):

```
 vim filename
Or
 vi filename
```

Vim/vi is a great editor, can also be used as a reader in "Normal Mode" or using -R option, it has many features that will help you in browsing through the file.

Comment: Shorter for `vim -R` is `view`. But keep in mind that it not likes redirections, as discussed in [xargs and vi - “Input is not from a terminal”](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44426/xargs-and-vi-input-is-not-from-a-terminal).

Comment: thanks @manatwork for the heads up! I have recently started using Vim and I like it because of its several features. Regarding redirections, I forgot about that, thanks for reminder. As of now, I am working on a remote VM, where I use ssh without GUI interface, therefore, Vim is of great use, when any other GUI editor cannot work, that's why I emphasized Vim here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cat` command to display the content of filename.

```
cat filename
```

Use `vim` command to edit file.

```
vim filename
```

Answer (score 1):

**Perl:**

```perl
~$ perl -pe ''  Sonnet_18.txt
```

**Raku:**

```perl
~$ raku -pe ''  Sonnet_18.txt
```

Sample Output:

```
Shall I compare thee to a summer’s day?
Thou art more lovely and more temperate.
Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,
And summer’s lease hath all too short a date.
Sometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,
And often is his gold complexion dimmed;
And every fair from fair sometime declines,
By chance or nature’s changing course untrimmed.
But thy eternal summer shall not fade
Nor lose possession of that fair thou ow’st,
Nor shall Death brag thou wand’rest in his shade,
When in eternal lines to time thou grow’st.
 So long as men can breathe or eyes can see,
 So long lives this, and this gives life to thee.
```

Clearly, `cat` is going to be the most popular answer to this question, but the code examples above will also provide the desired output (file courtesy of Shakespeare, via Project Gutenberg). However learning basic one-liners using Perl and/or Raku has its merits, simply because you can get an awful lot of work done with them.

*Grep through a file, return matching lines:*

```perl
~$ #Perl:
~$ perl -ne 'print if /eternal/'  Sonnet_18.txt
But thy eternal summer shall not fade
When in eternal lines to time thou grow’st.

~$ #Raku:
~$ raku -ne '.put  if /eternal/'  Sonnet_18.txt
But thy eternal summer shall not fade
When in eternal lines to time thou grow’st.
```

*Substitute one bit of text with another, redirect output to a new file:*

```perl
~$ #Perl:
~$ perl -pe 's/eternal/forevermore/g'   Sonnet_18.txt > new_sonnet.txt

~$ #Raku:
~$ raku -pe 's:g/eternal/forevermore/'  Sonnet_18.txt > new_sonnet.txt
```

https://perldoc.perl.org
https://docs.raku.org